# Borland C++ Builder LoadFromResourceID Results in EAccess Violation

Tags: c++, bitmap, c++builder, vcl

I'm using Borland C++Builder 5 to write a game program.  I'm trying to load a bitmap from a resource file I created.  I cannot get the bitmap to load from 
the resource file either by ID or by Name.  It will load from file, but I want
to use the resource file.  Loading from ID or Name results in the following error message at runtime:

> Project HoldemProbs.exe raised exception class EAcessViolation with message
>   'Access violation at address 0043F66E in module 'HoldemProbs.exe'.
>   Read of address 000003EB. Process stopped.  Use Step or Run to continue.

I'm pretty new to C++ and C++Builder, and I am sure I am doing something wrong.  I just can't figure out what.  I think it probably has something to do with the `HInstance` value, but I don't know what.

Below are relevant pieces of code:

ResRC.h

```
#ifndef RESRC_H 
#define RESRC_H
#define RC_REDBACK 1000
#endif
```

RedBack.rc

```
RC_REDBACK BITMAP "<MYSOURCEPATH>\RedBack.bmp"
```

HoldemProbs.cpp

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
USERES("HoldemProbs.res");
USEFORM("..\Source\HoldemCalc.cpp", Form1);
USERES("..\Source\RedBack.res");

WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int)
{
    try
    {
        Application->Initialize();
        Application->Title = "HoldemEval";
        Application->CreateForm(__classid(TForm1), &Form1);
        Application->Run();
    }
    catch (Exception &exception)
    {
        Application->ShowException(&exception);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

HoldemCalc.cpp

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <cstring.h>
#include <HoldemEval.hpp>
#include <Graphics.hpp>
#pragma hdrstop
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
#include <Graphics.hpp>
#include <ResRC.h>
#include "HoldemCalc.h"
#include <string>

#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;

__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    CardBackTst();               //Run test of card back bitmap useage
}
```

CardBackTst.cpp

```
void CardBackTst(void){
    Graphics::TBitmap* RedBack = new Graphics::TBitmap;
    Form1 -> Debug -> Text = DEBUGTEXT;     //See below for DEBUGTEXT
    RedBack -> LoadFromResourceID ((ARG1),RC_REDBACK); //See below for ARG1                      
}
```

There is an Edit Box called `Debug` used to display debug information. At various times, `DEBUGTEXT` has been (w/o surrounding `"`s):

```
"(int)(GetModuleHandle(NULL)"
"reinterpret_cast<int>(HInstance)"
"(int)HInstance"
"(int)(GetModuleHandle("<MYFINALPATH>\\HoldemProbs.exe"))"   // ANSI string
"RC_REDBACK"                     (This yielded the correct value -- 1000)     
"reinterpret_cast<int>(RedBack -> Handle)"
"(int)(Form1 -> Handle)"
```

At various times, `ARG1` has been each of the above values of `DEBUGTEXT`, except for `RC_REDBACK`. All have resulted in an `EAccessViolation` error.

The following statement to load from the resource name has been used 
with each `ARG1` value, with the same `EAcessViolation` result:

```
RedBack -> LoadFromResourceName ((ARG1),"MYPATH\\RedBack.bmp");
```

However, the following `LoadFromFile()` statement to load from the actual bitmap file does work:

```
RedBack -> LoadFromFile("MYPATH\\RedBack.bmp");
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with this code:

- `RedBack.rc` does not have a `#include "ResRC.h"` statement:

  ```
  #include "ResRC.h" // <-- add this!
  RC_REDBACK BITMAP "<MYSOURCEPATH>\RedBack.bmp"
  ```

  Without that, `RC_REDBACK` will not be `#define`d, and so the bitmap resource will be identified by the literal name `"RC_REDBACK"` and not by the ID number `1000`.  As such, you will have to use `LoadFromResouceName()` instead of `LoadFromResourceID()`:

  ```
  RedBack->LoadFromResourceName((unsigned)HInstance, "RC_REDBACK");
  ```

  Use a resource viewer tool to verify how your resources are actually identified in the final executable.
- inside of `CardBackTst()`, the global `Form1` pointer may not have been assigned yet, since the `TForm1` object is still being constructed.  `CardBackTst()` *should not* be relying on the global pointer at all.  It should take the Form pointer as an input parameter instead:

  ```
  //#include "ResRC.h"

  void CardBackTst(TForm1 *Form) {
      Graphics::TBitmap* RedBack = new Graphics::TBitmap;
      if (Form) Form->Debug->Text = DEBUGTEXT;
      //RedBack->LoadFromResourceID((unsigned)HInstance, RC_REDBACK);
      RedBack->LoadFromResourceName((unsigned)HInstance, "RC_REDBACK");
  }

  ...

  __fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
      : TForm(Owner)
  {
      CardBackTst(this);
  }
  ```

  A better solution would be to pass in the `TEdit` directly instead of the `TForm` itself:

  ```
  //#include "ResRC.h"

  void CardBackTst(TEdit *Debug) {
      Graphics::TBitmap* RedBack = new Graphics::TBitmap;
      if (Debug) Debug->Text = DEBUGTEXT;
      //RedBack->LoadFromResourceID((unsigned)HInstance, RC_REDBACK);
      RedBack->LoadFromResourceName((unsigned)HInstance, "RC_REDBACK");
  }

  ...

  __fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
      : TForm(Owner)
  {
      CardBackTst(Debug);
  }
  ```

  Or, use a callback function instead:

  ```
  //#include "ResRC.h"

  typedef void __fastcall (__closure *TCardDebugProc)(const String &);

  void CardBackTst(TCardDebugProc DebugProc) {
      Graphics::TBitmap* RedBack = new Graphics::TBitmap;
      if (DebugProc) DebugProc(DEBUGTEXT);
      //RedBack->LoadFromResourceID((unsigned)HInstance, RC_REDBACK);
      RedBack->LoadFromResourceName((unsigned)HInstance, "RC_REDBACK");
  }

  ...

  __fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
      : TForm(Owner)
  {
      CardBackTst(&LogDebug);
  }

  void __fastcall TForm1::LogDebug(const String &DebugText)
  {
      Debug->Text = DebugText;
  }
  ```